# Sending data via tcp sockets. Does this look right?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm implementing a client server mechanism where some data is collected from client and sent to the server listening for client calls. I'm doing this using a tcp socket, the data looks like:

```
Files:20;Users:100;Availability:0.65
```

Is this in compliance with standards of sending data over tcp sockets ? These are aggregates and I'll be sending it every 5 seconds. How can I improve it ?

Comment: I've heard much praise for the Google Protocol Buffers library, but I have no first hand experience. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: Is there a line ending or zero byte at the end of the message? If not, how will the receiver know that the '5' is the last byte of the message and isn't, say, followed by a '2'?

Comment: How do I indicate the end of message and start of message?

Comment: @Phoenix: However you want. It's up to you. You can use a newline character, a zero byte, you can send the length before each message, and so on. Read the specifications for a few existing protocols.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for sending data over TCP sockets, at least not from user space. The only thing you have to be aware of is that TCP is stream based, so you have no guarantee that message borders will be respected. For example, one recv()-call can result in the application receiving multiple packets.

In order to improve your data format, you could for example remove the descriptions. If you know that each message will contain the same "fields" and in the same order, then they may be redundant.

Comment: but shouldn't a bufferedReader on the other end receiving the packets be able to get the entire message ?

Comment: It will get the entire message, that is guaranteed by TCP's reliability. However, you can never be sure that a call to recv()/read()/... will give you exactly one message. Depending on the amount of data available in the OS kernel buffers (i.e., data has arrived in order), it might return half a message, the entire message or 1.5 messages. In order words, you need some way to separate messages, for example a \0 or \n at the end of each line.

Comment: More precisely, a read can deliver anything between one byte and the buffer length, both inclusive, and it may consist of a partial message, the end of one message and the beginning of another, one or more complete messages, ... There is basically no such such thing as a message in TCP.

Comment: How can I indicate the message boundaries in java ?

Comment: @Phoenix In your application protocol.

Comment: @Phoenix: The issue is not whether you'll get the entire message. The issue is *knowing* that you got the entire message. Say you read "Files:20;Users:100;Availability:0.65". Is that the entire message? How do you know it's not "Files:20;Users:100;Availability:0.651"?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't look right. Whether you realize it or not, you've already made some decisions that may bite you later on, such as reserving ':' and ';', and indeed '\n', so they can't appear in data unless you provide an escape mechanism: have you considered that?

There are plenty of existing protocols to copy or indeed just reuse.

Comment: Like what simple protocols can i use ?

Comment: Google Protobufs. JSON. XML. Java.util.Properties format. Serialization. HTTP header format. Type-length-value format with DataOutputStream. CORBA IIOP. ...